# Origin doesn't load the game!

Tags: origin, the-sims-3, sims-3-supernatural

I already own a few Sims 3 expansion packs, and I recently purchased Sims 3: Supernatural.

It went on without problems, and I clicked the Launcher to play it, but the Launcher wouldn't load at all.

So I did the usual and restarted / logged off etc to see if that would help, but it hasn't done anything!

I have now uninstalled Sims 3: Supernatural but now Origin keeps popping up this new window saying...

> "Only one instance of Origin can run at a time. Please check other
>   Windows accounts to see if Origin is running."

I recently purchased a Windows phone and used my account from my PC (the only account on the PC) for my phone aswell.

Has that done something to stop Origin from working properly?

Answer (score 3):

No that won't have done anything, that error message is just referring to occurances on your computer.

Press Ctrl+alt+delete

Go to processes

Find origin.exe

click end process

Then try and run origin again

Comment: Ctrl+alt+del is wrong, to open the task manager you have to press ctrl+shift+esc

Comment: @Jubatus At least on Win7, you can access the Task Manager from the ctrl+alt+del menu.

Comment: @Kareen You can use Ctrl+alt+delete in windows to open task manager long before windows 7. However Ctrl+shift+ESC is the faster shortcut for most people